# Kubernetes container env variables and Github Actions input variables

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, yaml, environment-variables, github-actions

I'm trying to solve a setup of a deployment, in our dev team we are working with a kubernetes cluster which is deployed through a pipeline in github actions.

The issue is that when we define and consume environment variables from github, and later we try to consume them in the deployment in some fields these are relpaced and in some other it doesn't get expanded.

This is the Github Job configuration:

```
name: Build and Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
       ENVIRONMENT:
         description: environment to deploy
         default: dev
         required: false
defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: app-springboot-sqs-docker
jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: deploy
        run: |
          bash ./devops/scripts/runpipeline.sh
        env:
          DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT: ${{ github.event.inputs.ENVIRONMENT }}
```

And in the deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-springboot-sqs-docker-v1
  namespace: app-$DEPLOY-ENVIRONMENT # here it gets replaced correctly, e.g app-dev
  labels:
    app: app-springboot-sqs-docker
    version: v1
```

but below in container section (of the same file, i had striped some data):

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app-springboot-sqs-docker
          image: # the image location
          env:
            - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
              value: $DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT # here it doesn't get replaced
```

so, because it doesn't get replaced spring tries to load the $DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT (literally) incorrectly. I'd tried to replace also like $(DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT) and ${DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT} without success.

Also i'd tried to do it with a ConfigMap with the same result:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: env-variables
  namespace: app-$DEPLOY-ENVIRONMENT # here get replaced as app-dev
data
  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: $DEPLOY-ENVIRONMENT # here it still gets literal "$DEPLOY-ENVIRONMENT"
```

Is there a way to pass that value to the container? or at least a workaround?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does the `runpipeline.sh` do? Usually with kubernetes manifests containing environment variables I would use `envsubst` to set enviroment variables defined in the manifests e.g. `envsubst < configmap.yaml | kubectl apply -f -`

Comment: I've discovered that devops area is using [tekton](https://tekton.dev/) on this cluster, so `runpipeline.sh` only sets some variables for it and then calls tekton. So as a "patch" we used tekton to replace the env variable. Could you explain more about this `envsubst`?

Comment: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/envsubst.1.html